# How to create a java jar file with two packages and a text file in it using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My project has got two packages and a text file. I use the text file to take inputs. I've tried out several tutorials on how to create jar file and I was able to create a jar file but my GUI application does not function, like, when I click a button it is supposed to show some output based on some inputs but it does not, in my jar file.

Comment: Hey there, it's hard to help you if you are not very specific, please ready http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Go into your root directory where you have the two packages and the file. 
Open cmd prompt and execute the command below:

```
jar -cj project.jar dir1 dir2 file.txt
```

This will create project.jar. 
dir1, dir2 and file.txt will be packaged inside the jar.
For example if the first package is **com.company.foo** and seconds is **com.company.bar**
what you have to do is (note that we specify just the package root, which is **com**)

```
jar -cf project.jar com file.txt
```

Then you can invoke the Main class, lets suppose it is in **foo**, like this:

```
java -cp project.jar com.company.foo.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "Export" > "Export As" > "Java/(Runnable) JAR file".
If your text file was inside the project folder, it should be packed with the rest.